# Adjust table column with in % with table overflow

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have table of two cells inside div of width:70% and table width:97%. similarly i want first column to take 30% and 2nd column of width 70% of total table. which works fine until i add display:block and overflow: auto on table class! and column totally became invalid unless i use px instead of % on column width.

if i use column in % with .CustomTableBlock_01 display:block and autoflow then this what happened

[image]

but if I don't use .CustomTableBlock_01 display:block and autoflow then % works or if I use column with in px

[image]

I want to set all width in % with autoflow!!

many thanks

### Razor code

```
<div class="form-group">

 @Html.Label("Element", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })

 <div class="CustomTableBlock_01">
   @if (Model._Element != null)
    {
     <table class="customTable_01">
       <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="SC_a1">
             @Html.DisplayName("Element")
          </th>

          <th class="SC_a2">
             Marking-Scheme
          </th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             @foreach (var item in Model._Element)
               {
                <tr>
                 <td class="SC_a1"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.ElementTitle) </td>

                 <td class="SC_a2">
                    <input type="button" value="Add" name="button" data-id="@item.ElementID" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
             }
           </tbody>
         </table>
        }
   </div>

 </div>
```

### CSS

```
.CustomTableBlock_01{
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 14px;
padding-right: 15px;
float:left;
width:70%;
height:200px;
background-color:green;
}

.customTable_01{
background-color:yellow;

display:block;
width:97%;
height: 200px;
overflow:auto;
}

td.SC_a1,
th.SC_a1{
width:30%;

background-color:grey;
}

td.SC_a2,
th.SC_a2{
width:70%;
background-color:azure;
}
```

Comment: If you change the `display` of a table, it's no longer a table and none of the normal table rules apply any longer. So ask yourself what you want. Do you want a table, or do you want a bunch of blocks with other blocks inside?

Comment: i want table so in order to use horizontal overflow of table height say example 200px, what i am missing form picture... many thanks once again for your help

Comment: So basically, it works the way you want to, as a table? OK, so you shouldn't use `display:block`. Now it's not very clear what you want, what's supposed to happen when a cell does become wider than its designated width. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: i want define table and its columns width in % to cope with responsive web design... plus table height is 200px with horizontal scroll-bar, ideally applies to tbody of table but if is too much to ask then I can live scroll-bar on table itself. I have 2 columns in table, first column I want 30% width and 2nd column takes 70% width  ... many thanks once again